# Issue with oneVPL samples

Tags: intel, encode, onevpl

I am unable to run any VPL samples on my host machine. When I am trying to run any hello samples it's showing the below error.

I installed basetoolkit and am trying to run the hello_encode sample with the below command.

> ./hello-encode -i ./P.i420 -w 1920 -h 1080

When I run the above command, it always throws the below error.

> Cannot create session -- no implementations meet selection criteria
> Encoded 0 frames

These are the OS details:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

These are the CPU details:

> Architecture:        x86_64 CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit Byte
> Order:          Little Endian CPU(s):              16 On-line CPU(s)
> list: 0-15 Thread(s) per core:  2 Core(s) per socket:  8 Socket(s):
> 1 NUMA node(s):        1 Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel CPU family:
> 6 Model:               158 Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM)
> i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz Stepping:            12 CPU MHz:
> 4523.145 CPU max MHz:         5000.0000 CPU min MHz:         800.0000 BogoMIPS:            7200.00 Virtualization:      VT-x L1d cache:
> 32K L1i cache:           32K L2 cache:            256K L3 cache:
> 16384K NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason for getting such error is that you haven't sourced your environment variables. Source the setvars.sh script given in oneapi folder to proceed further:

1. Run as root/super user:

> sudo su

2. Source environment variables as follows:

> ```
> source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
> ```

3. Run the command that you've been trying to run:

> ```
> ./hello-encode -i <input file> -w 1920 -h 1080
> ```

Hope this helps!